# Visio Web Access hyperlinks

Tags: 2010, hyperlink, visio, ie-11

I have a problem with Hyperlinks in Visio. I use Visio Web Access and Sharepoint 2010.

If I use chrome browser, a single click on the visio shape will navigate to the desired URL, If I use IE 11, nothing happens when I click. The only way I can manage to navigate using IE11, is by ctrl+click to open the shape menu, and then click the URL from there.

I have tried:

Using compatibility mode for the site in IE11
Adding the site to the list of trusted sites.

Zooming and Pan is deactivated for the web drawing in the web part properties section.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have someone got this to work at all? IE11, Sharepoint 2010 and Visio Web Access with Hyperlinks??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi finally got it working by using this workaround:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ef224758-b613-48ca-8c19-8f6f3b02bb9e/how-to-single-click-hyperlink-in-visio-web-access-webpart-to-go-to-the-url?forum=sharepointcustomization

Basically it is a JavaScript in a content editor webpart, which gets the URLs of the shapes in the Visio diagram. I have modified it slightly to allow for external URLs instead of URLs that links to other Visio drawings.